# How can I bypass the Language request

Tags: django, django-unittest, pytest-django

On each of my view I have a function that return the request language code of the browser. But when I run my unittest my views I have an error:

```
applications\emplois\views.py:74:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <applications.emplois.views.IndexView object at 0x0000000006270048>

    def language(self):
        """Return the user default language"""
>       language = language_set(self.request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
E       AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'LANGUAGE_CODE'

applications\emplois\views.py:64: AttributeError
---------------------------- Captured stdout setup ----------------------------
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
=================== 1 failed, 11 deselected in 5.97 seconds ===================
```

views.py

```
def language_set(language):
    if "-" in language:
        return (language.split('-')[1]).upper()
    else:
        return language.upper()

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    """
    this is the ROOT page
    return a list of Jobs
    """
    template_name='emplois/index.html'
    context_object_name='latest_jobs_list'
    paginate_by = 10

    def language(self):
        """Return the user default language"""
        language = language_set(self.request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
        language = language.upper()
        return language

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Return a list of Jobs that have an EXPIRATION DATE
        greater than Now() and a default Language
        """
        #import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
        return Job.objects.filter(language=self.language(),\
              EXPIRYDATE__gt=datetime.now())\
            .order_by('EXPIRYDATE')
```

tests:

```
import pytest
from django.core import mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
from django.http import Http404
from django.test import RequestFactory
from mock import patch
from mixer.backend.django import mixer
pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db

from applications.emplois import views


class TestIndexView:
    def test_anonymous(self):
        req = RequestFactory().get('/')
        resp = views.IndexView.as_view()(req)
        assert resp.status_code == 200, 'Should be callable by anyone'
```

How can I bypass the Language request because I don't use a browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a `RequestFactory` you can give the request any request parameters. In this case you are looking for the `request.LANGUAGE_CODE` so the solution is to set the `LANGUAGE_CODE` in your test's `RequestFactory`.

You can see the documentation for the `RequestFactory` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/advanced/).

So solution is:

```
def test_anonymous(self):
    req = RequestFactory().get('/')

    # Here is the change.
    req.LANGUAGE_CODE = "en"

    resp = views.IndexView.as_view()(req)
    assert resp.status_code == 200, 'Should be callable by anyone'
```